# Updating populated array in MongoDB - patch request is being accepted but not updating with new item

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a populated array stored in a MongoDB database with a new item using Javascript & Node.js, and while the patch request is technically successful, it does not update with the ID of the new item, and checking the console, only the old IDs are passed through to the DB, not the newly created one. To be more specific, I am building out an "Add new question" feature for a quiz application.

I tried to utilize `.depopulate()`, thinking it was something related to `.populate()` that was causing the issue but received an error stating that it was not a function, and am now thinking that is not the issue. Is there something I am overlooking with my code? Various snippets are included below.

Route (which works in other functions that update other aspects of the quiz):

```
router.patch('/quizzes/:id', requireToken, removeBlanks, (req, res, next) => {
  delete req.body.quiz.owner

  Quiz.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(handle404)
    .then(quiz => {
      requireOwnership(req, quiz)

      return quiz.updateOne(req.body.quiz)
    })
    .then(() => res.sendStatus(204))
    .catch(next)
})
```

How questions are stored in the quiz Mongoose model:

```
  questions: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Question'
  }]
```

Here, I am pulling out the existing objectIds, as my 'questions' Mongoose schema is `type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,`

```
const reAddQuestionIds = () => {
  const quiz = store.quizData.questions

  quiz.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    store.questions.push(arrayItem._id)
  })
}
```

Event function to create question & add the newly created question to the quiz:

```
const onAddQuestion = event => {
  event.preventDefault()

  const form = event.target
  const formData = getFormFields(form)
  // call above function
  reAddQuestionIds()

  api.addQuestion(formData)
    // get the newly created question
    .then(res => api.getOneQuestion(res.question._id)
      // push the id of the new question to the array of existing questions
      // this line seems to be the issue?
      .then(res => store.questions.push(res.question._id)))
    .then(store.quizData.numOfQuestions++)
    // call ajax function to update api
    .then(api.addQuestionToQuiz()
      .then(console.log))
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

API call:

```
const addQuestionToQuiz = () => {
  console.log('store.questions: ', store.questions)
  return $.ajax({
    url: config.apiUrl + '/quizzes/' + store.quizData._id,
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token token=${store.user.token}`
    },
    data: {
      quiz: {
        questions: store.questions,
        numOfQuestions: store.quizData.numOfQuestions
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Now, a unexpected thing that happens, is in the above console log: when I check what is currently in the stored array in Chrome devtools, it shows there being one less object than what should be in there (i.e. if there were two questions previously, then I added the new question, it still just shows two objects), but when I expand, the new ID is there and it shows it as the correct length. And again, in checking what is passed through to the backend route, only the previously-created IDs are passed through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: error was in the API call to the event handler function. I removed adding the code incrementing the number of questions (moved this to the API call), and in my third .then(), made sure to take the response and pass it to the `api.AddQuestionToQuiz()` call.

Discovered by logging `store.questions` upon successful creation of the new question, and saw that all questions were there, whereas the `console.log` in the API call function was missing the newly created question.

```
  api.addQuestion(formData)
    .then(res => api.getOneQuestion(res.question._id)
      .then(res => store.questions.push(res.question._id)))
    .then(res => api.addQuestionToQuiz()
      .then(console.log))
    .catch(console.error)
```